# Guessing the winner of a 1v1 with a weighted coin

Tags: probability

Let us say that you have weighted coin (P(Heads)=0.6, P(Tails)=0.4) and you are using said coin in order to guess who is the winner of a Tennis game (If Heads pick player 1 and if tails pick player 2).

Is the probability of guessing the winning player still 0.5 or are they not equal due to the weighted coin?

-Edit,
Nothing is known about the competitors and draws are not permitted

Comment: "*You are using said coin in order to guess who is the winner of a Chess game*"  And... do we know anything about our competitors?  Is it understood that player 1 will actually win the game half of the time and player 2 will win the other half of the time?  (*In reality, this seems a terrible assumption since many games do end in draws*)

Comment: In the extreme... in the case that player 1 is a grandmaster at chess and player 2 is a beginner, our *probability* (*don't use the word odds... it doesn't mean the same thing*) of guessing correctly by using your weighted coin will be higher than 0.5.  In the other extreme, if player 1 is the obviously weaker player, then the probability your using the coin to guess will give you a probability lower.

Comment: Fair enough about the game might end in a draw. Changed the question for a tennis game to avoid it. No, nothing is known about the competitors.

Comment: If we assume *a priori* that both competitors are equally skilled and equally likely to win, then it will so happen that our probability of guessing correctly by using the coin will be exactly $0.5$.  Note that $\Pr(\text{Pl1 win}) = \Pr(\text{Heads})\Pr(\text{Pl1 win}\mid \text{Heads})+\Pr(\text{Tails})\Pr(\text{Pl1 win}\mid \text{Tails}) = 0.6\cdot 0.5 + 0.4\cdot 0.5 = 0.5$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, I think that pretty much answers my question